# Toggle Flot Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, flot

I have 9 working Flot Chart plots distributed in an HTML file, but 7 of them are just not as relevant as the 1st and the 2nd ones, and so I want to "Toggle" them in order to be able to Hide/Show them only if they are needed, as "extra" information. I've been looking for info but I've just found info on how to toggle series on a plot, and what I want is to show/hide the entire plot area to keep the webpage "clean".

I've tried the following:

```
<script>
    // Flot Charts code...
</script>
<div id="placeholder">
</div>
<script>
  $( "#button" ).click(function() {
     $( "#placeholder" ).toggle();
  });
</script>
<button id="button">Show/Hide</button>
```

But it just shows the button and the plots but when I click on the button, the plots do not disappear... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: That should work, can you reproduce the error in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yes, I'll try it and in 1 minute I'll post it here

Comment: I've written in the following JSFiddle the same as I have in this post and it worked perfectly (http://jsfiddle.net/jamitzky/9x7aJ/), however in my html code it does not work, maybe because I have it in the following way?:
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="placeholder3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="placeholder4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="placeholder5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: I've reproduced the content of the JSFiddle in my HTML file and it shows the plot perfectly but the content does not hide. I believe the error comes from misplacing the scripts...

Comment: Right, you bind the click event to the button before you have the button in your HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind the click event to the button before you have the button in your HTML.

Swap these or use `$(function() { ... });` in your jQuery to run the binding after your DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

i've faced something like this before. all i did was just toggling the div.

```
<div id="userchart">
      <center>
          <canvas id="barchart" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
      </center>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#toggle-user").click(function()
    {
        $('#userchart').slideToggle(500);
    });
```